# Searching for academic jobs within a specific city

Tags: job-search

I am currently in the job market and due to personal issues I am geographically limited and cannot relocate. I was wondering what would be a good strategy to go about the job search. There are only 3 institutions that I could potentially work on. Realistically I know that it might take a while for opening to come in my field but I was wondering if there is anything I can do in the mean time. I know this is not common in academia, and we go where the jobs are. I really want to continue in academia but I am unsure how to move forward.

Comment: If you're looking for jobs at three institutions you know well, what sort of answer are you expecting us to come up with?

Comment: I do not have personal or professional connections at these institutions. I just recently had to relocate. My colleagues have all searched for jobs without geographic constraints. I'm looking for any comments/ guidance on doing the job search with this restriction.

Comment: What country are you in (so that we know what the academic system is like)?  What field are you in?  What kind of academic job are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to stay on the job market (whether for those 3 institutions or in general), the best thing you can do is stay competitive in terms of research productivity. That usually means taking a postdoc or other full-time research position where you can publish as much as possible.

However, there is a "shelf life" to postdocs. If you are a postdoc for too long, hiring committees start to wonder why you haven't been hired, and may reject you thinking there's something wrong. For instance, in my field it is common to have 0-2 years of postdoc, so someone who has been a postdoc for 5 years may find it more difficult to get interviews.

Answer (score 0):

Many institutions hire "Adjunct Instructors". Unfortunately the pay is terrible, but most don't object if you so something similar at another university. You might be able to cobble together a modest income for a while, though you would need to work long hours and deal with commuting/scheduling, etc.

If you visit an appropriate department and let them know of your needs you might find something. If you tell them you hope for a long term job if it comes up, they might be able to "keep you in mind".

Such a position might also let you develop some relationships with the local faculty, leading to research opportunities.

You could also explore research opportunities with local firms that require your skills.

Answer (score 0):

There may be organisations in your city which, although they're not universities, nevertheless have academia-like activities: think-tanks; government (local, national, EU, UN...) research institutes; third-sector research institutes; pressure groups that like to apply their pressure in an evidence-based, scholarly way; research labs belonging to industry associations; public examination boards; even some for-profit companies.  You could try broadening your search to include those.

Answer (score 0):

#### Do what you need to do to "get your foot in the door"

Since you are limited to only three universities, this is a situation where it may be worthwhile to make some sacrifices in order to get your foot in the door at one of them.  For example, it might be worth applying for positions that are at a lower level than what you would ideally like (and are qualified for) elsewhere.  Universities are sometimes suspicious of applicants that apply at a lower level than their qualifications appear to suit, so make it clear that you are especially interested in remaining in this city and you are willing to start at any level to do so.  Obviously the other thing to do is just to produce as much good research output as you can and remain as competitive as you can for when positions arise.